# Which mountain huts might be open outside of Mt. Fuji's regular season?

Tags: japan, hiking, mountain-climbing, mount-fuji

I'm considering climbing Mt. Fuji in mid-June, slightly before the regular season starts (regular season is July to mid-September). That way, it might be less crowded and a little more peaceful.

I'm not worried about the climb itself personally, as I am an experienced mountaineer and can judge conditions well enough to determine whether to continue or turn back.

However, most climbing schedules include one night in a mountain hut part of the way up, where you get dinner and sleep before going up to the summit. **Is there an easy way to find out which huts might be open earlier than the official start?**

Unfortunately, carrying sleeping & cooking gear is just not logistically possible for me on this trip (though it would definitely resolve this issue, and probably even be more fun).

Comment: Watch out for the kitsune!

Comment: Pretty sure none of them is open off-season.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them. Many huts close before the end of season and start later the beginning. There is no need to spend time in huts but they are convenient for hot drinks and food and water if you don't want to lift it up whole. The end and the beginning of seasons are not just random days. Beginning get delayed sometimes because trails are blocked by snow.

And beginning of July is not really crowded.I hiked in July several times of total 9. Most crowded is the end of August. I stayed in the hut only first time.